# Fetching relative column value with group by

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the latest date among the column values mentioned but also fetching relative column values for the respective Max(date)

**My Query:**

```
select gd.desk_id, gd.created_by, max(gd.created_at) from dodem gd where gd.desk_id in ('abc123', 'xyz123') 
and gd.pot_id='123S2' group by gd.desk_id;
```

Now I have the following data
column - desk_id, created_by, created_at, pot_id

```
abc123, sam, 2020-10-12 14:53:27, 123S2
xyz123, max, 2020-10-12 14:53:27, 123S2
xyz123, max, 2020-10-12 15:53:27, 123S2
```

With above query I should be getting two rows

```
abc123, sam, 2020-10-12 14:53:27, 123S2
xyz123, max, 2020-10-12 15:53:27, 123S2
```

which is absolutely working as it should be but the query is getting **wrong results** when I have similar data but different created_by then it does not fetches created_by of max(created_at) rather which comes first.

**Example:**

```
abc123, sam, 2020-10-12 14:53:27, 123S2
xyz123, max, 2020-10-12 14:53:27, 123S2
xyz123, jim, 2020-10-12 15:53:27, 123S2
```

**Query Gives:**

```
abc123, sam, 2020-10-12 14:53:27, 123S2
xyz123, max, 2020-10-12 15:53:27, 123S2
```

If you see I am getting **max** rather I should be getting **jim** for **latest date corresponding column value**.

Please suggest improvement in my query.

Comment: Probably learn to write a proper query to get the correct result.  Please look up how to use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Eric if you could point out the correction that would be helpful rather criticizing. Like I  said I wrote the same query please suggest where I am wrong

Comment: @Kramer pls see the several different solutions in the duplicate question.

Comment: @Kramer When you learn how to use proper `GROUP BY`, your problem will resolve by itself.  Your query is not even valid.  It won't even execute in most dbms system.  Even MySQL 8 won't execute your code.

Comment: @Eric sorry my friend this query gives result although its wrong and I have resolved it with duplicate question